# My modal doesn't show when I click a button

Tags: javascript, react-native, bootstrap-modal

Here I have my modal component. I am making an app that I want a button to open this modal that I use in multiple places like opening a preview or deleting options.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { CSSTransition } from 'react-transition-group';

import Backdrop from '../Backdrop/Backdrop';
import '../Modal/Modal.css';

const ModalOverlay = (props) => {
  const content = (
    <div className={`modal ${props.className}`} style={props.style}>
      <header className={`modal__header ${props.headerClass}`}>
        <h2>{props.header}</h2>
      </header>
      <form
        onSubmit={
          props.onSubmit ? props.onSubmit : (event) => event.preventDefault()
        }
      >
        <div className={`modal__content ${props.contentClass}`}>
          {props.children}
        </div>
        <footer className={`modal__footer ${props.footerClass}`}>
          {props.footer}
        </footer>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
  return ReactDOM.createPortal(content, document.getElementById('modal-hook'));
};

const Modal = (props) => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {props.show && <Backdrop onClick={props.onCancel} />}
      <CSSTransition
        in={props.show}
        mountOnEnter
        unmountOnExit
        timeout={200}
        classNames="modal"
      >
        <ModalOverlay {...props} />
      </CSSTransition>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default Modal;
```

And here I use this modal for showing up deleting options.

```
const DocumentItem = (props) => {

  const [showConfirmModal, setShowConfirmModal] = useState(false);
  const showDeleteWarningHandler = () => {
    setShowConfirmModal(true);
  };

  const calcelDeleteHandler = () => {
    setShowConfirmModal(false);
  };

  const confirmDeleteHandler = () => {
    setShowConfirmModal(false);
    console.log('Delete!');
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Modal
        show={showConfirmModal}
        onCancel={calcelDeleteHandler}
        header="Are you sure?"
        footerClass="document-item__modal-actions"
        footer={
          <React.Fragment>
            <Button inverse onClick={calcelDeleteHandler}>
              CANCEL
            </Button>
            <Button danger onClick={confirmDeleteHandler}>
              DELETE
            </Button>
          </React.Fragment>
        }
      >
        <p>
          Do you want to proceed and delete this document? Please note that it
          can't be undone thereafter.
        </p>
      </Modal>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```

I don't understand why my screen goes all black, transparent but my modal doesn't show.
How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Does an elemnent with the id `modal-hook` exist when you call the modal? Can you post what Backdrop looks like or better make a minimum working code-sample to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Yes, I call my modal in index.html into a div, next to the div that calls root. And the Backdrop component is this one `const Backdrop = (props) => {
  return ReactDOM.createPortal(
    <div className="backdrop" onClick={props.onClick}></div>,
    document.getElementById('backdrop-hook')
  );
};`